# How to get all links in a webpage using blue prism?

Tags: blueprism

I want to extract all the links that available in the webpage and to read it. But using HTML mode we are able to spy single link.Not as an list of links . Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You can try using dynamic path, but my attempts doing that were really slow.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Navigate stage action "Insert Javascript Fragment" to insert Javascript code that will read all `a` tag's `href` attributes and output them in a pipe-delimited fashion. The function below should get you started:

```
function getLinks() {
    var output = ""; // instantiate string variable
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); // enumerate all anchor tag nodes
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) { // loop results
        if (i != 0) { // if this isn't the first item in the list...
            output = output + "|"; // add a pipe between each URL
        }
        output = output + links[i].getAttribute("href"); // append the href attribute for each link
    }
    return output; // return the enumerated string
}
```

The only remaining line of Javascript that would have to be added would be functionality to place the pipe-delimited list to a specific location on the page for Blue Prism to read from.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for example action "Get HTML" and then use regular expressions to get every link tag , and get the properties of "href" attribute.